# k8s pod readiness probe fails with connection refused, but pod is serving requests just fine

Tags: kubernetes, openshift

I'm having a hard time understanding why a pods readiness probe is failing.

```
  Warning  Unhealthy  21m (x2 over 21m)  kubelet, REDACTED  Readiness probe failed: Get http://192.168.209.74:8081/actuator/health: dial tcp 192.168.209.74:8081: connect: connection refused
```

If I exec into this pod (or in fact into any other I have for that application), I can run a curl against that very URL without issue:

```
kubectl exec -it REDACTED-l2z5w /bin/bash
$ curl -v http://192.168.209.74:8081/actuator/health
$ curl -v http://192.168.209.74:8081/actuator/health
* Expire in 0 ms for 6 (transfer 0x5611b949ff50)
*   Trying 192.168.209.74...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Expire in 200 ms for 4 (transfer 0x5611b949ff50)
* Connected to 192.168.209.74 (192.168.209.74) port 8081 (#0)
> GET /actuator/health HTTP/1.1
> Host: 192.168.209.74:8081
> User-Agent: curl/7.64.0
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 200 
< Set-Cookie: CM_SESSIONID=E62390F0FF8C26D51C767835988AC690; Path=/; HttpOnly
< X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
< X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
< Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
< Pragma: no-cache
< Expires: 0
< X-Frame-Options: DENY
< Content-Type: application/vnd.spring-boot.actuator.v3+json
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Date: Tue, 02 Jun 2020 15:07:21 GMT
< 
* Connection #0 to host 192.168.209.74 left intact
{"status":"UP",...REDACTED..}
```

I'm getting this behavior from both a Docker-for-Desktop k8s cluster on my Mac as well as an OpenShift cluster.

The readiness probe is shown like this in kubectl describe:

```
    Readiness:  http-get http://:8081/actuator/health delay=20s timeout=3s period=5s #success=1 #failure=10
```

The helm chart has this to configure it:

```
    readinessProbe:
      failureThreshold: 10
      httpGet:
        path: /actuator/health
        port: 8081
        scheme: HTTP
      initialDelaySeconds: 20
      periodSeconds: 5
      successThreshold: 1
      timeoutSeconds: 3
```

I cannot fully rule out that HTTP proxy settings are to blame, but the k8s docs say that HTTP_PROXY is ignored for checks since v1.13, so it shouldn't happen locally.

The OpenShift k8s version is 1.11, my local one is 1.16.

Comment: Are you able to hit that url from the node? Does kubelet logs on the node say anything more?

Comment: `The kubelet uses readiness probes to know when a container is ready to start accepting traffic` and kubelet runs on node. see if url is reachable from node. it could be something wrong with network plugin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Describing events always show the last event on the resource you are checking. The thing is that the last event logged was an error while checking the `readinessProbe`.

I tested it in my lab with the following pod manifest:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: readiness-exec
spec:
  containers:
  - name: readiness
    image: k8s.gcr.io/busybox
    args:
    - /bin/sh
    - -c
    - sleep 30; touch /tmp/healthy; sleep 600
    readinessProbe:
      exec:
        command:
        - cat
        - /tmp/healthy
      initialDelaySeconds: 5
      periodSeconds: 5
```

As can be seen, a file `/tmp/healthy` will be created in the pod after 30 seconds and the `readinessProbe` will check if the file exists after 5 seconds and repeat the check after every 5 seconds.

Describing this pod will give me that:

```
Events:
  Type     Reason     Age                    From                 Message
  ----     ------     ----                   ----                 -------
  Normal   Scheduled  7m56s                  default-scheduler    Successfully assigned default/readiness-exec to yaki-118-2
  Normal   Pulling    7m55s                  kubelet, yaki-118-2  Pulling image "k8s.gcr.io/busybox"
  Normal   Pulled     7m55s                  kubelet, yaki-118-2  Successfully pulled image "k8s.gcr.io/busybox"
  Normal   Created    7m55s                  kubelet, yaki-118-2  Created container readiness
  Normal   Started    7m55s                  kubelet, yaki-118-2  Started container readiness
  Warning  Unhealthy  7m25s (x6 over 7m50s)  kubelet, yaki-118-2  Readiness probe failed: cat: can't open '/tmp/healthy': No such file or directory
```

The `readinessProbe` looked for the file 6 times with no success and it's completely right as I configured it to check every 5 seconds and the file was created after 30 seconds.

What you think is a problem is actually the expected behavior. Your Events is telling you that the `readinessProbe` failed to check 21 minutes ago. It means actually that your pod is healthy since 21 minutes ago.

Comment: Thank you, I just came to the same conclusion. I thought my pod was unhealthy, and that was causing the service to not route requests, but it turns out my Traefik ingress controller was misconfigured and was producing 404s.